# if $\mu(X)$ is finite then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu \{x: |f(x)|\geq n\}=0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $(X,\mathcal F, \mu)$ be measurable space with $\mu(X)<\infty$. a) Prove that if function $f$ is measurable on $X$ then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu \{x: |f(x)|\geq n\}=0.$$
>
> b) Can we discard the hypothesis  $\mu(X)<\infty$?

I tried to use Chebyshev inequality but it doesn't work. Can anyone give me some hints? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

We cannot discard the hypothesis of finiteness of $\mu$. With the normal Lebesgue measure and with $f(x) = x$, say, we have $\mu\{x:|x|\ge n\} = \infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: How to prove the first part?

Comment: What "first part"? The only omitted step here is that $\{x:|x| \ge n\} = (-\infty, -n] \cup [n, \infty)$, and this obviously has infinite measure.

Comment: Oh, you added "a)" and "b)" after I answered your question. sranthrop's answer covers "a)".

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n:=\{x\in X\ :\ |f(x)|\geq n\}$ for $n\in\mathbb N_0$. Then $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ for each $n$. Now use that $\mu$ is continuous from above. Note that this requires that at least one of the sets $A_n$ has finite measure, and this is the case since $X$ has finite measure.

As pointed out in another answer, the assumption that $\mu(X)<\infty$ cannot be discarded.

Comment: I don't see that $lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(A_n)=0$??

Comment: As I said, use the continuity from above, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=\mu(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N_0} A_n)$. Do you see it now? :)